# Apply RoleHierarchy to Client Roles

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

For the security roles in my application we defined a RoleHierarchy, but when we tried to check client-roles with `@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.clientHasRole('somerole')")` we notized that by default our Hirarchy is not appllied to Client-Roles.

Is there some additional config required beyond setting the roleHierarchy on the `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` does not apply the RoleHierarchy to Client-Authorities. To solve that i added my own ExpressionHandler that does by extending it.

```
public class HierarchicalOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
    public HierarchicalOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public StandardEvaluationContext createEvaluationContextInternal(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation mi) {
        StandardEvaluationContext ec = super.createEvaluationContextInternal(authentication, mi);
        ec.setVariable("oauth2roles", new HierarchicalOAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods(authentication, getRoleHierarchy()));
        return ec;
    }
}

public class HierarchicalOAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods extends OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods {

    private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;
    private Authentication authentication;

    public HierarchicalOAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods(Authentication authentication, RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        super(authentication);
        this.authentication = authentication;
        this.roleHierarchy = roleHierarchy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean clientHasAnyRole(String... roles) {
        if (authentication instanceof OAuth2Authentication) {
            OAuth2Request clientAuthentication = ((OAuth2Authentication) authentication).getOAuth2Request();
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> clientAuthorities = roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities(clientAuthentication.getAuthorities());
            if (clientAuthorities != null) {
                Set<String> roleSet = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(clientAuthorities);
                for (String role : roles) {
                    if (roleSet.contains(role)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now i have the option to use #oauth2roles.clientHasAnyRole(...) if i need to.